# MVC3 Routing strange behavior

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I found something strange with routing...

I´m testing a MVC3 application in Visual Studio Web Express 2012

- I created a new MVC3 application to isolate the problem
- I added the following route before the default route:

  ```
      routes.MapRoute(
          "default_localization",
          "{language}/{country}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
          new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
      );
  ```
- Then without any other change (there are no areas anything just the initial files after creating the project), I ran the application and at first sight everything was working fine. Since it is a new application there are two links at the top of the page:

  - Home
  - About

The action links look like:

```
<li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
<li>@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")</li>
```

Then this is what is happening:

- When the browser URL is: `http://localhost:54870/`

  - The Home link is: `http://localhost:54870/`
  - The About link is: `http://localhost:54870/Home/About`

  HTML

  ```
  <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="/Home/About">About</a></li>
  ```

  Which is OK
- **But after clicking the About link**, the browser URL is: `http://localhost:54870/Home/About`

  - The Home link becomes: `http://localhost:54870/Home/About`
  - The about link becomes: `http://localhost:54870/Home/About/Home/About`

  They still execute the correct action even when the link is messed up.

  HTML

  ```
  <li><a href="/Home/About">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="/Home/About/Home/About">About</a></li>
  ```

If I remove my custom routing everything works as expected

- Why is this happening?
- How can I fix it?

Comment: You do not set default values for country and language. Maybe this is causing the 'confusion',....

Comment: I was thinking something like that, but my logic tells me that since my route contains two tokens (language and country), this route should not match a route that only specifies the controller and action tokens therefore the default route should be picked it up instead... but this is not happening. What am I missing?

Comment: Did you try to see the source code of the html page in the browser? What link do you have within your *About*?

Comment: I just added the rendered HTML in both cases and how the ActionLinks are generated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just found the problem

Basically I read several routing articles and finally I got it, my problem was that my custom route was been picked up **always after I clicked the About link**

Why?

Let's consider it:

When my URL was `http://localhost:54870/`, my custom route was not picked up because I didn't have default values for {language} and {country} therefore my route didn't match

But when my URL was `http://localhost:54870/Home/About` my custom route was **always picked up** because the route engine *assumed that Home/About were the {language} and {country} segments* and since  I had default values for {controller} and {action} the rout simply was a match

Well I learnt my lesson and I learnt more about routing. In the future I'm planning to follow the [KISS principle when defining routes](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2010/01/25/kiss-your-asp-net-mvc-routes.aspx)

Comment: What were your languages like? "en-US", etc? You could've used a constraint like [a-z]-[A-Z] to make it match..

Comment: @SimonWhitehead yes indeed, with constraints I had solved it as well, but I really wanted to learn and understand the root problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing your route with something like this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "default_localization",
    "{language}/{country}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    new { language = "en", country = "US", controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

See if that works.

Hope this is of help to you.